# Position two images one above the other (responsive). Problem with transform in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with css transform. I managed to make two images one above the other but this solution works in Safari but doesn't work in Chrome. Any suggestions?

HTML CODE

```
<div class="all" style="">

        <div class="parent">
            <img src="img/pizza2@2x.png" class="pizza">
            <img src="img/elipse2.svg" class="elipse">
        </div>


    <div class="text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis provident, cumque labore adipisci quibusdam ea eveniet dolores blanditiis esse maiores numquam totam commodi cum eos debitis officia, consequatur aliquam temporibus tenetur doloribus vel. Repudiandae quasi eius officiis enim dicta laboriosam quidem iste officia possimus, molestiae nobis magni? Saepe accusantium similique quos aliquid animi facilis soluta doloribus commodi quisquam sapiente ab autem tenetur distinctio optio voluptates earum assumenda sunt possimus quae vero, debitis id delectus. Tempora cupiditate quis est beatae totam maxime eaque similique sunt quisquam? Quasi nostrum obcaecati ea veritatis explicabo, suscipit iste placeat autem harum sequi dignissimos officiis esse enim quos fugiat assumenda nisi repellat voluptates? Voluptatem ex sapiente fugit debitis reprehenderit commodi aspernatur enim illo, tenetur ipsum vero molestias asperiores, esse facilis exercitationem aliquam accusantium vitae facere quisquam maxime. Doloremque autem dolor saepe corporis, laboriosam, ipsa tempore eligendi nihil voluptates deserunt pariatur minima? Sit commodi sapiente aliquam, sequi repellat explicabo fugit quasi maiores beatae, ipsa itaque? Accusantium autem vel facilis inventore, recusandae quia est earum unde, labore perferendis aperiam rem delectus illum dolores dolorem ipsum! Quae dolorum soluta voluptatibus inventore, optio perferendis voluptate alias accusantium dignissimos quas dolores commodi quo aperiam illum repellendus ullam ea sint sequi nostrum!</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
body {max-width: 1600px; margin: 0 auto;}
    .all { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr; padding: 20px 0 0px; }
   
    .parent { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; max-width: 500px;}
    .text { padding: 50px; }

    
    .pizza {
        width: 95%;
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .elipse {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .all { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
                padding: 50px 0 50px;
        }
       
    }
```

Chrome Screen
[image: Chrome Screen]

Safari screen
[image: Safari]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your code. (Without the comments)

```
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* W3C */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari & Chrome */
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Firefox */
      -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Internet Explorer */
       -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%); /* Opera */
}
```